# Unable to read XML Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

**Stacktrace:**

```
ERROR: HHH000196: Error parsing XML (2) : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-mapping'.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.dao.FlightDAO.convertDAO(FlightDAO.java:70)
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.service.impl.FlightDataImpl.loadFlightData(FlightDataImpl.java:78)
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.flightServiceController.MainService.main(MainService.java:58)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.legacyReadMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
    at com.nagarro.flightSystem.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-mapping'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1901)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.legacyReadMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:325)
    ... 16 more
```

mapping file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping package="com.nagarro.flightSystem.model">
    <class name="Flight" table="flight">
    <property name="flightNo" type="string">
        <column name="flight_no" />
    </property>
    <property name="depatureLocation" type="string">
        <column name="depature_location" length="3" />
    </property>
    <property name="arrivalLocation" type="string">
        <column name="arrival_location" length="3" />
    </property>
    <property name="validTill" type="string">
        <column name="valid_till" />
    </property>
    <property name="flightTime" type="string">
        <column name="flight_time" />
    </property>
    <property name="flightDuration" type="string">
        <column name="flight_duration" />
    </property>
    <property name="fare" type="string">
        <column name="fare" />
    </property>
    <property name="seatAvailability" type="string">
        <column name="seat_availability" length="1" />
    </property>
    <property name="flightClass" type="string">
        <column name="flight_class" length="2" />
    </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

```
package com.nagarro.flightSystem.model;

public class Flight implements Comparable<Flight> {
    /** 
     * Holds a string value in flight no.
     */
    private String flightNo;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in depatureLocation.
     */
    private String depatureLocation;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in arrivalLocation.
     */
    private String arrivalLocation;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in vaildTill.
     */
    private String validTill;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in flightTime.
     */
    private String flightTime;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in flightDuration.
     */
    private String flightDuration;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in fare.
     */
    private String fare;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in seatAvailability.
     */
    private String seatAvailability;
    /**
     * Holds a string value in flightClass.
     */
    private String flightClass;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new flight.
     */
    public Flight() {

    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new flight.
     *
     * @param flightNo the flight no
     */
    public Flight(String flightNo) {
        this.flightNo = flightNo;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the flight no.
     * 
     * @return the flight no
     */
    public String getFlightNo() {
        return flightNo;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the flight no.
     * 
     * @param flightNo
     *            the new flight no
     */
    public void setFlightNo(String flightNo) {
        this.flightNo = flightNo;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the depature location.
     * 
     * @return the depature location
     */
    public String getDepatureLocation() {
        return depatureLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the depature location.
     * 
     * @param depatureLocation
     *            the new depature location
     */
    public void setDepatureLocation(String depatureLocation) {
        this.depatureLocation = depatureLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the arrible location.
     * 
     * @return the arrible location
     */
    public String getArribleLocation() {
        return arrivalLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the arrible location.
     * 
     * @param arrivalLocation
     *            the new arrible location
     */
    public void setArribleLocation(String arrivalLocation) {
        this.arrivalLocation = arrivalLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the valid till.
     * 
     * @return the valid till
     */
    public String getValidTill() {
        return validTill;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the valid till.
     * 
     * @param validTill
     *            the new valid till
     */
    public void setValidTill(String validTill) {
        this.validTill = validTill;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the flight time.
     * 
     * @return the flight time
     */
    public String getFlightTime() {
        return flightTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the flight time.
     * 
     * @param flightTime
     *            the new flight time
     */
    public void setFlightTime(String flightTime) {
        this.flightTime = flightTime;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the flight duration.
     * 
     * @return the flight duration
     */
    public String getFlightDuration() {
        return flightDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the flight duration.
     * 
     * @param flightDuration
     *            the new flight duration
     */
    public void setFlightDuration(String flightDuration) {
        this.flightDuration = flightDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the fare.
     * 
     * @return the fare
     */
    public String getFare() {
        return fare;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the fare.
     * 
     * @param fare
     *            the new fare
     */
    public void setFare(String fare) {
        this.fare = fare;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the seat availability.
     * 
     * @return the seat availability
     */
    public String getSeatAvailability() {
        return seatAvailability;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the seat availability.
     * 
     * @param seatAvailability
     *            the new seat availability
     */
    public void setSeatAvailability(String seatAvailability) {
        this.seatAvailability = seatAvailability;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the flight class.
     * 
     * @return the flight class
     */
    public String getFlightClass() {
        return flightClass;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the flight class.
     * 
     * @param flightClass
     *            the new flight class
     */
    public void setFlightClass(String flightClass) {
        this.flightClass = flightClass;
    }

@Override
    public int compareTo(Flight flightObject) {
        return (this.fare).compareTo(flightObject.fare);
    }

}






    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(flightObject);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if(tx!=null){
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more how do you read this file...

Comment: You need to provide your Java code, not just the XML.

Comment: Maybe it's because of lack of schema/DTD reference in the mapping XML?

Comment: what is DTD reference

Comment: add this to ur mapping xml...<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">